# 1 person, 2 accounts

Tags: discussion, support, questions, users, accounts

I answered this [Output the highest average using functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668352/output-the-highest-average-using-functions) question, but the OP seems to know very little about the programming language he uses.

He asked me for more traditional/old/legacy solutions and I provided them to him. Then he asked me to continue via email, I refused. However, he accepted my answer.

Now he un-accepted it, and I saw this [searching for highest grade then output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671591/searching-for-highest-grade-then-output#47671591) question, which asks for the same problem, and it's just like he used my legacy solutions to move further and then post his problem again, and with a different account.

This is *not* cool, what should we do?

---

PS: I wonder whether the following image can be applied to accounts as well? :O :P (kidding)

[image]

Comment: I voted to close the second question as a duplicate of the first one.

Comment: 100% help-vampire.

Comment: I hope (s)he doesn't get away with this @MartinJames! I flagged the question for moderator attention. Donald Duck, I did too, but this is not enough. This person has to be "punished".

Comment: That user is extremely annoying.  Obviously intends to get others to do ALL its work and has an arrogant, entitiled 'tude.  Worst kind of user:(

Comment: This: 'What are you talking about lol? If you don't want to help , don't reply, simple' when using a debugger was suggested, is rude and insulting: 'What do you mean, I should do some work?  That's stupid - I came to SO to get you drones/slaves to do my work for me and you suggest I do stuff?  If you won't obey my commands, just shut up'.   Yech...

Comment: Do not feed them with answer after midnight, they will duplicate.

Comment: I did notice that you don't seem to mind answering crap questions.  Nobody can tell you not to do that, although I'm sure many SO users wish you wouldn't, but if you get bitten by them then you shouldn't be too surprised.  It is the cost of answering crap.  Just move on.

Comment: Right. Down-vote and vote to close from the get-go.

Comment: When you see something like this, it's usually a sign of someone creating multiple accounts to evade question bans (or sometimes a classroom of kids simultaneously cheating on a homework assignment). In this case, I have reason to believe these were at least their sixth and seventh accounts, so I deleted the rest, locked their credentials, and prevented them from posting more at their location for a little while. That usually stops askers like this.

Comment: @HansPassant I had a NOC duty, I was...vulnerable! And ready to be fired with crap. However my point for the question and my flag, was to "catch that guy" and disable his account or something, like Brad Larson did, thanks!